# Is there a Document Management System where user role or permission could be tagged to document?

Tags: document-management, cloud-storage

Is there a DMS solution where I could store my documents and tag relevant user role and permission to the document instead of maintaining a seperate DB table to map document to user role/permission? Appreciate the help. The roles and permissions are from a custom application and should not rely on the DMS application.

Comment: I started using AWS S3 for this use case. But it could not be purely used for this. An additional layer should be maintained to capture user and permissions (since the users in my case could not be IAM users in AWS). I anyone has a suggestion about a solution that could be used right out of the box please do let me know. Thanks